# desktop wallpaper

Tags: cocoa, desktop, desktop-wallpaper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically changing desktop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468074/programmatically-changing-desktop-image)

Hi,
  I want to set the image as the wallpaper through cocoa program. I have to set the dynamically downloaded images as the wallpaper.  My problem is, first time its  correctly changing, but if i click for next time, no action is performed, the same wallpaper remains.

Kindly help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?  That way people can see possible see where the mistake is.