# Objective C or C /qt set OSX desktop wallpaper?

Tags: macos, background, set, wallpaper

I would really like a snippet of code that would take in a string location for a file & makes that the desktop background.

It can be in c++ or Objective C,  but I'm just having no luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Programmatically changing desktop image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468074/programmatically-changing-desktop-image), in particular

```
setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:
```

Comment: That's fantastic. I've found the Sample project Apple Inc. has posted to be the most helpful. [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DesktopImage/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008860) for anyone that want's to know. Thanks Joe!